# Vb.net Linq order by special

Tags: vb.net, linq

In vb.net Linq, I want to sort a list by a value, but if the value is null, it should use another value.

Sample :

```
Class Item
    Public _Id As Integer
    Public _FullName As String
    Public _Acronym As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fullName As String, ByVal acronym As String)
        Me._Id = id
        Me._FullName = fullName
        Me._Acronym = acronym
    End Sub
End Class

 Sub Main()
        Dim itemList As New List(Of Item)
        itemList.Add(New Item(1, "AZZ", "A"))
        itemList.Add(New Item(2, "BBB", "B"))
        itemList.Add(New Item(3, "FFF", "F"))
        itemList.Add(New Item(4, "An item", Nothing))

        itemList = (From l In itemList Order By l._Acronym).ToList

        For Each i In itemList
            Debug.Print(String.Format("{0}{2}{1}", i._Acronym, i._FullName, IIf(i._Acronym IsNot Nothing, " - ", "")))
        Next
    End Sub
```

Result with this sort :

```
An item
A - AZZ
B - BBB
F - FFF
```

Result I want :

```
A - AZZ
An item
B - BBB
F - FFF
```

Because "An" should be after "A".

The sort need to use Acronym, but if acronym is nothing, it should use Fullname.
We cant put the value of FullName into Acronym in the result. it could be done as a method to sort but the result list need to keep the original value of acronym.

Comment: Is there another OR better way than : itemList = (From l In itemList Order By String.Format("{0}{2}{1}", l._Acronym, l._FullName, IIf(l._Acronym IsNot Nothing, " - ", ""))).ToList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#

```
ItemList.OrderBy(x=>x._Acronym??x._FullName);
```

VB.NET

```
ItemList.OrderBy(Function(x) If(x._Acronym, x._FullName))
```

Comment: OP asked for VB.NET not C#

Comment: As much as I like C#, this asks for VB. -1.

Comment: tanks for the vb.net translation. its shorter than others answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VB.NET's `IF` function

```
itemList = (From l In itemList Order By If(l._Acronym Is Nothing, l._Id, l._Acronym)).ToList
```

Comment: its like my first comment but shorter, I dont know why I didnt think of that. itemList = (From l In itemList Order By IIf(l._Acronym Is Nothing, l._FullName, l._Acronym)).ToList

Comment: @forX I prefer `If` to `IIf`. It's short-circuited and strongly typed

Answer (score 0):

What about adding an extra property to your class - Something along the lines of:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Sorter As String
    Get
        If _Acronym Is Nothing Then Return _FullName Else Return _Acronym
    End Get
End Property
```

Then you just change your LINQ to sort based upon that property rather than _Acronym.

Would that work for you??
(PS - I did this really quickly, I'm not sure I created that property correctly, but it should be what you're looking for, I believe)

Comment: The sorter is not called with order by

Comment: I don't understand.. Try this. Add in the property I gave you and then change your linq statement to `itemList = (From l In itemList Order By l.Sorter).ToList`. I tested it now and it worked...